# How to append an "checkbox" into dialog by using pywin32

Tags: python, pywin32

I met an problem here.
I could successfully create an dialog and add an button by code below,
because I know the constant "128" is the control "button" by exsiting example
but I do not know which one can be used for "checkbox" or "radiobutton"?

---

```
import win32ui
import win32api
import win32con
from pywin.mfc import dialog

# Window frame and title
dlg = [ [title, (0, 0, 300, 392), style, None, (8, "MS Sans Serif")], ]
dlg.append([128, u"Output", IDC_BTN_OUTPUT, (142,56,50,14), win32con.BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON])
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the source code and the documentation, the dialog template here is a list whose first item is a `PyDLGTEMPLATE` instance followed by a series of `PyDLGITEMTEMPLATE` instances.

The documentation says this about the first member of the `PyDLGITEMTEMPALTE` structure:

> [0] string/int : windowClass
>
> The window class. If not a string, it must be in integer defining one of the built-in Windows controls. If a string, it must be a pre-registered windows class name, a built-in class, or the CLSID of an OLE controls. Built-in classes include:
>
> ```
> Control Type    String Class Name
> Check Box       Button
> Combo Box       ComboBox
> Command Button  Button
> Header          SysHeader32
> Label           Static
> List Box        ListBox
>                 SysListView32
> Option Button   Button
> Tab             SysTabControl32
> Text Box        Edit
>                 RICHEDIT
> Tool Bar        ToolbarWindow32
> Tool Tips       tooltips_class32
>                 tooltips_class
> Tree View       SysTreeView32
> ```
>
> The built-in windows controls are:
>
> ```
> Integer Value    Window Type
> 0x0080           Button
> 0x0081           Edit
> 0x0082           Static
> 0x0083           List box
> 0x0084           Scroll bar
> 0x0085           Combo box
> ```

So while you *could* use the integer constant 0x85 (or 133 decimal), I'd **strongly** recommend you use the string class name `'ComboBox'` instead.  These string names are, unsurprisingly, the same as the built-in Windows class names [documented on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#system).

Comment: Thanks very much Adam! This solve my problem,and I finally realize that an A checkbox is a Button with the BS_CHECKBOX or BS_AUTOCHECKBOX style!!!